# Striptime Python partial matching

Tags: python

I have the follwoing format for my date `2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009`. I want to extract the date, so I have used the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

However, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/d774911/PycharmProjects/GlobalData/Test2.py", line 4, in <module>
date_object = datetime.strptime('2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009', '%Y-%m-%d')
File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\Python34\lib\_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T18:42:26.000009
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like ISO 8601 format. If that's the case, see this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python

Comment: Oh, and also: it's not "striptime", it's `strptime`, from the compound of `str`ing `p`arse `time`. The Python function is named after the POSIX function of the same name. (See `man 3 strptime` for details.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the remains of your string to date format.So replace `'%Y-%m-%d' with` with `'%Y-%m-%dT18:42:26.000009'` :

```
>>> date_object = datetime.strptime('2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009', '%Y-%m-%dT18:42:26.000009')
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 23, 0, 0)
```

Or as a more general way you can use `dateutil.parser` :

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 23, 18, 42, 26, 9)
```

And if you just want the `date` :

```
>>> parse('2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009', fuzzy=True).date()
datetime.date(2014, 2, 23)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have many records (more than 600,000 records) and won't be able to match them using the same value above. Ideas?

Comment: @user3089324 Welcome. in that case you can use some date parsers  like `dateutil`

Comment: @user3089324 checkout the edit!

Comment: wonderful solution！！！

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
time="2014-02-23T18:42:26.000009"
print re.sub('T.*','',time)
```

**output: 2014-02-23**

*Further you can use the* `strip('-')` *to return a list containing* **['2014', '02', '23']**